# Confused when changing from Lebesgue Integral to Riemann Integral

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm currently studying Stochastic Calculus via Shreve II. I have a question about switching back and forth between Lebesgue and Riemann Integral.

Suppose we have a non-negative random variable $X$ defined on a probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$ with exponential distribution:$$P(X<x) = 1-e^{-\lambda x}$$

Written in Lebesgue Integral, the expected value of $X$ can be written as: $$E[X] = \int_{\{{\omega \mid X(\omega) \geq 0}\}}^{ }X(\omega)dP(\omega)$$

**Question:** How exactly do we switch from $\omega$ in the Lebesgue Integral to $x$ in Riemann integral so that we get $$E[X] = \int_{0}^{\infty}x\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx$$

Does this have to do with the fact that we should define our $\Omega$ to be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $B(\mathbb{R})$ and simply define $X(\omega) = \omega$ for non-negative $\omega$'s?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you know the formula for expected value given a density?

Comment: Yes, in Riemann integral for this case it's simply $$E[X] = \int_{0}^{\infty}x\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx$$ I believe I understand the intuition, however I'm a little stuck on notation regarding switching from $\omega$ to $x$.

Comment: What exactly is confusing you? The switch from Lebesgue integration to Riemann integration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not really a matter of changing from Lebesgue integral to Riemann integral, it is a matter of changing measures (sort of a change of variables).

By definition, given $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ a random variable, $E[X]=\int_{\Omega}X$.

$X$ defines a measure $\widetilde{m}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, called the *push-forward*, by $\widetilde{m}(A)=P(X^{-1}(A)).$ By definition, this measure is invariant under $X$, and hence
\begin{equation}  \tag{1}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f d\widetilde{m}= \int_{\Omega}f \circ XdP.
\end{equation}
The equality follows from the usual arguments (prove for characteristics, simple functions, then use convergence. Recall that $\mathbf{1}_A \circ X=\mathbf{1}_{X^{-1}(A)}$).

Let $h$ be the density of $X$. We then have, by definition of density,  that $\widetilde{m}(A)=P(X^{-1}(A))=\int_A h dm$ for any $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. By "change of variables" (which is Theorem $1.29$ in Rudin's RCA for example, but is just another instance of repeating the argument of proving for characteristics, simple functions and using convergence), we have:
\begin{equation}  \tag{2}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f d\widetilde{m}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f \cdot h dm.
\end{equation}
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$,
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f \cdot h dm= \int_{\Omega}f \circ X dP. $$
Taking $f=\mathrm{Id}$ yields
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} x h(x)dx= \int_{\Omega} X dP=E[X]. $$
Taking $f=\mathrm{Id}\cdot\mathbf{1}_I$, where $I$ is some interval (for example, $(0,+\infty)$ as in your case), we have
$$\int_{I} x h(x)dx= \int_{X^{-1}(I)} X dP, $$
recalling again that $\mathbf{1}_A \circ X=\mathbf{1}_{X^{-1}(A)}$. Since $P(X<0)$ in your case is $0$, this last integral is actually equal to the integral over the whole space, and hence to $E[X]$, which gives your equality.

Comment: How do you justify $\int_\mathbb{R} f\cdot hdm = \int_\mathbb{R} xh(x)dx$?. Is it absolutely necessary to introduce Riemann-Stieltjes integral or perhaps absolute convergence of riemann integral is enough?

Answer (score 1):

By definition as a random variable, $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable with a distribution function

$$F(x) = P[X < x] = 1- e^{-\lambda x}$$

We can construct a non-decreasing sequence of approximating step functions $(\phi_n)$ converging pointwise to $X$ and  of the form

$$\phi_n = \sum_{j=1}^{m(n)}x_{j-1}^{(n)}\mathbf{1_{A_j^{(n)}}}$$

where $A_j = \{\omega: x_{j-1}^{(n)} \leqslant X(\omega) < x_j^{(n)} \}$ and $[0,\infty) = \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty[x_{j-1}^{(n)},x_j^{(n)})$ with $m(n) \to \infty$ and  $x_j^{(n)}- x_{j-1}^{(n)} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

By the monotone convergence theorem,

$$E[X] = \lim_{n \to \infty}E[\phi_n] = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^{m(n)} 
x_{j-1}^{(n)}P(A_j^{(n)}) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^{m(n)} 
x_{j-1}^{(n)}[F(x_j^{(n)}- F(x_j^{(n)}] $$

Recognizing the limit on the RHS as that of a Riemann-Stieltjes sum we get

$$E[X] = \int_0^\infty x \,dF(x) = \int_0^\infty xF'(x) \, dx = \int_0^\infty x \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \, dx$$